# Hyperlink to a specific row or cell based on dropdown value

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I hope everyone is having a great Friday.

I am trying to create a dynamic hyperlink which takes the searched name in (G2) as an input and allow me to jump to that specific row where the searched name is located  (in this example the hyperlink should jump to cell B8).

Based on some internet search i found something similar which can be applied in excel but i don't think it's working on google sheets. Please find below the function that i applied in (I2)

```
=hyperlink("#"&Cell("address",index(Sheet1!B5:B9,MATCH(G2,Sheet!B5:B9,0))),"Click here to move to row")
```

Unfortunately it isn't working, and it isn't even shown as a hyperlink (blue underlined text).Can you guys help me understand more what i did wrong, and if there is a better way to do this task.

Let me give another example, Lets say i picked Nishant from the dropdown list in G2,
I want that when i click on I2 the link would make me jump to B9 in this example.

Thank you for your help.
Appreciate it.

[image: Sample of the isssue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=hyperlink("#gid=1860191576&range=B"&MATCH(G2, B5:B9,0)+4,"Click here to move to row")
```

replace 1860191576 by your grid id

Comment: Works perfectly, thnx alot sir.